# Change file ownership for external persistent volume of MySQL Container

Tags: docker, containers, chown

This is a tricky one.

I have the official MySQL Docker container with a persistent volume.
I realized that the performance was quite bad, so I stopped the container, moved the files on the host system from the HDD to an SSD and changed the mountpoint, so the users within the container can access the files at the same place again.

Because I moved the files, the ownership got transferred to the host root user.

When I start the container, the root user inside the container finds the files and detects that the file permissions are wrong. It tries to change them with chown, which it obviously doesn't have permission for.

Now how can I transfer the file ownership to the container user again?
I need the UID, but I can't exec in the container to get it, because it immediately stops.

Any idea what I could do?

Comment: `docker run -u` the database container with the matching host uid.  See "Running as an arbitrary user" in the [Docker Hub `mysql` image page](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql).

Comment: The default ownership is mysql:mysql (typically 999:999). Can you paste the output of `ls -ld <data dir on your host>` and `docker logs <mysql container>`?

Comment: @gohm'c 

The output:

`root@server:/mnt/sdc1# ls -ld
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jan  1  1970 .
root@server:/mnt/sdc1# cd database/
root@server:/mnt/sdc1/database# ls -ld
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 Jan  2 22:40 .
`
When I try to "chown -r 999:999 /database" I get "Operation not permitted for several files".
I assumed it's the immutable flag, but when I try to change it I get "chattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device while reading flags in database/"

Comment: And the docker logs only state for example:
`chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql/wordpress/wp_posts.ibd': Operation not permitted`
for all files.

Comment: On the SSD mounted directory, what if you `mkdir datadir` then run a temporary mysql  like `docker run -it -v datadir:/var/lib/mysql --rm mysql`. See if you get permission error? My guess is no unless something wrong with the way you mount the SSD device. You can also check the datadir default ownership/permission this way on your host, `root` is unlikely the issue here regardless if it is host or container (mysql come with gosu).